# Can't change system locale in Embedded Standard 7

Tags: embedded, locale, windows-embedded-7

I have Windows Embedded Standard 7 US English, but for one application I need to change language for non-unicode programs, so that it displays correctly.
When I go to Region and Language, Administrative tab, the Change System Locale buton doesn't work -- when I click it, nothing happens.
I added the WinEmb-International and WinEmb-Lpk-Setup packages to the online image, but it didn't help.
What else can I do?